# Code Coverage for Catch Blocks using EclEMMA

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, eclemma

I have catch block, i want to execute the catch block. My Class file is,

```
    public class TranscoderBean implements TranscoderLocal {
    public byte[] encode(final Collection<?> entitySet) throws TranscoderException {
        Validate.notNull(entitySet, "The entitySet can not be null.");
        LOGGER.info("Encoding entities.");
        LOGGER.debug("entities '{}'.", entitySet);

        // Encode the Collection
        MappedEncoderStream encoderStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            // Create the encoder and write the the DSE Logbook messgae
            encoderStream = new MappedEncoderStream(outputStream, this.encoderVersion);
            encoderStream.writeObjects(new ArrayList<Object>(entitySet), false);
            encoderStream.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception while encoding entities", e);
            throw new TranscoderException("Failed to encode entities", e);
        }
        finally {
            if (encoderStream != null) {
                try {
                    encoderStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while closing the endcoder stream.", e);
                    throw new TranscoderException("Failed to close encoder stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

My Test Class file is,

```
public class TranscoderBeanTest {

    private TranscoderBean fixture;

    @Mock
    MappedEncoderStream mappedEncoderStream;
    @Test
    public void encodeTest() throws TranscoderException {
        List<Object> entitySet = new ArrayList<Object>();
        FlightLog log1 = new FlightLog();
        log1.setId("F5678");
        log1.setAssetId("22");

        FlightLog log2 = new FlightLog();
        log2.setId("F5679");
        log2.setAssetId("23");
        entitySet.add(log1);
        entitySet.add(log2);

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        try {
            Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(this.mappedEncoderStream).close();

            Mockito.doReturn(new IOException()).when(this.mappedEncoderStream).close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] encode = this.fixture.encode(entitySet);
        Assert.assertNotNull(encode);
    } 
}
```

I have tried, Mockito.doThrow and Mockito.doReturn methods but still the catch block is not executed. What am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To test a try-catch block, you can use a TestNG way which consists in implementing a test method with the following annotation `expectedExceptions`.
The code of this method, you have to implement it in order to provoke this exception, so the `catch` block will be executed.

You can have a look at `http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations`

Comment: Thank You, but we are using JUnit and Mockito.

Comment: The same in JUnit. Have a look at https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Exception-testing

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right test class. I do not see any reference to TranscoderBean in your

Comment: For future reference, this sort of response would be better as a comment to the original question.

Comment: Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(this.mappedEncoderStream).close(); <-- This isn't going to work since you are setting the expectation on the mappedEncoderStream reference in the Test class, but the actual close is called on mappedEncoderStream in the TranscoderBean class (which in this case is not even a mocked object)

Answer (score 0):

You expect Mockito to do things that it does not claim to do:

```
Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(this.mappedEncoderStream).close();
```

This statement asserts that whenever someone calls `close()` on the mapperEncoderStream-Object will receive an `IOException`. You never call `close`.

Try to add `mapperEncoderStream.close();` after your Mockito-actions and the catch block will be entered - but note: this won't help you with your problem, since mockito cannot help here.

For your problem you can consider following alternative:

rewrite

```
encoderStream = new MappedEncoderStream(outputStream, this.encoderVersion);
```

to

```
encoderStream = createMappedEncoderStream(outputStream);

MappedEncoderStream createMappedEncoderStream(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
  return new MappedEncoderStream(outputStream, this.encoderVersion);
}
```

this lets you inject the mock as dependency.

Then init your fixure like this:

```
fixture = new TranscoderBean() {
  MappedEncoderStream createMappedEncoderStream(ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream) {
    return mappedEncoderStream; //this is your mock
  }
}
```

This injects the mock into your TranscoderBean.encode method.

Then change your mock Annotation:

```
@Mock(answer=CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
MappedEncoderStream mappedEncoderStream;
```

This is needed, because your encode method does not only call `close` on `mappedEncoderStream`, but also `writeObjects` and `flush`. These calls may throw exceptions so they have to be mocked or replaced by calls to the real object.

prune your test like that

```
@Test(expected=TranscoderException.class)
public void encodeTest() throws TranscoderException {
    //... same as above
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    Mockito.doThrow(new IOException()).when(this.mappedEncoderStream).close();

     this.fixture.encode(entitySet); //this will throw an exception
}
```

This does the following:

- the encode method does not return `null`! It throws a `TranscoderException`, so it is placed as `expected`
- override the `close` method with exception throwing
- call encode